# Disable certain parameters from being logged in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, parameters

I have noticed that whenever any action is executed by any controller in Ruby on Rails certain logs are written out automatically to the log files, for example:

```
Processing by CasesController#update as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"XAAgI8MGxIIyqcBTUqtHvqjechgNHqxKLtZAVIaceZSuhEskQA6i2mjbItbbruabPMPWGM8AXKDWNdnqJRCGBw==",
"versionId"=>"9",
"type"=>"case", 
"queue"=>"filing", 
"disposition"=>"Filed",
 "assignee"=>"abc",
 "decisionDate"=>"2020-05-19",
 "filingDate"=>"2020-05-19",
  "accounts"=>[{"lineOfBusiness"=>"ACCS",
  "obfuscatedMerchantId"=>"A1JLF6PVG3MPCN", 
  "fpsAccountId"=>"",
  "productAccountId"=>"",
  "includeInInvestigation"=>"yes",
  "includeInFiling"=>"yes"}],
  "relatedItems"=>[{"itemType"=>"OBSERVATION_ID",
  "itemValue"=>"RI:1-MPI:1-PI:4839201-JI:10334165-RRD:13-MAY-20-EQR:Rule_ACCS_SAM_MultiACCSBankAccounts-CID:A1JLF6PVG3MPCN"},
 {"itemType"=>"IWB_TASK_ID", "itemValue"=>"7017140401"}],
 "button"=>"", "id"=>"cab90a9e-78e9-6d58-c5c8-c4b3424d0751"}
```

I want to avoid certain sensitive parameters from being logged, for example I want to avoid `versionId` from being logged. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to it) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops showing up as unanswered in the searches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can exclude sensitive parameters from logging by adding them to `config.filter_parameters` like described in the official [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> `config.filter_parameters` used for filtering out the parameters that you don't want shown in the logs, such as passwords or credit card numbers. It also filters out sensitive values of database columns when call `#inspect` on an Active Record object. By default, Rails filters out passwords by adding `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]` in `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`. Parameters filter works by partial matching regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Can we define different filters for different controllers? for example:- 
`xyz` is sensitive in controller A but not in controller B.

Comment: This only affects logging right? Like it doesn't prevent these values from being stored or from being passed into the actual controller correct?

Comment: @Jwan622 That is correct. This configuration only affects the console or log file output.

Comment: @DarshanBhandari You can add `xyz` in `filter_parameters`. And in `controller B`, you can manually print log, Rails.logger.info "xyz: #{params[:xyz]}"

Comment: @DarshanBhandari No, that is not supported out of the box by Rails because this is a global configuration option. If you need something like that, then you will need to build that on your own, for example, by overriding this configuration option in before actions.